# Customize Legend Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, legend

I am showing a legend coming from a geoserver.
The SLD defining the layer is scale depending. 
Calling the GetLegendGraph like [this](http://vps143339.ovh.net:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=Caesaria:tabula-30C-section_3857&legend_options=fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:14;bgColor:0xFFFFEE;dpi:91) results in a legend that shows both scales.

I read about the possibility to define the image with the `RULE` option, but I couldn't get it working.

Here is my SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>tabula-30C-section_3857</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>tabula-30C-section_3857</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>&gt; 40 %</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>45.9</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>1000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2.1873365E7</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#7a0177</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.600000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>100.000000</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>20 % - 40 %</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>1000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2.1873365E7</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#f768a1</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.600000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>48.000000</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>&lt; 20 %</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.4</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>1000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2.1873365E7</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#feebe2</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.600000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>24.000000</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>&gt; 40 %</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>45.9</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>2.1873365E7</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>6.0E8</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#7a0177</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.600000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>60.000000</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>20 % - 40 %</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>2.1873365E7</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>6.0E8</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#f768a1</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.600000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>24.000000</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>&lt; 20 %</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.4</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>CS_rate</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>2.1873365E7</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>6.0E8</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#feebe2</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.600000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>12.000000</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

And my GetLegendGraphic call:

```
http://vps143339.ovh.net:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=Caesaria:tabula-30C-section_3857&legend_options=fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:14;bgColor:0xFFFFEE;dpi:91
```

How do I have to change the call to only get one of the scales?

Comment: where do you do the GetLegendGraphic call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because GeoServer (and all WMS Servers) doesn't know which map client is making the request for the legend you need to let it know what scale your map is at. So you need to pass in the `SCALE` parameter with your `getLegendGraphic` call, so it becomes something like:

```
http://vps143339.ovh.net:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=Caesaria:tabula-30C-section_3857&legend_options=fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:14;bgColor:0xFFFFEE;dpi:91&SCALE=1001
```

Which gives:

[image: example legend]

The full list of possible legend parameters is [fully documented](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/).